# Terraform taint with multiple resources

Tags: terraform

I have a need to taint a bunch of resources in my pipeline to force recreation of these. As I keep my state in remote backend, every `terraform taint` needs to:

- lock the storage
- download the state
- taint the resource
- upload the state
- release lock

and repeat that 30 times or so. Can't be done in parallel, so it takes much more time than I'd be happy with. `terraform taint` does not like multiple resources on the taint command. Is anyone aware of a method to speed this up?

Comment: What is the higher level thing you're trying to achieve here? Such mass tainting seems like a weird pattern to me and I'm wondering if there might be a better way of achieving this that is native to Terraform. A similar request for wildcard taints was closed with [this comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/18637#issuecomment-411557127) also saying that there might be a better approach than mass tainting. There's also an open issue tracking this [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22117).

Answer (score 2):

Terraform taint command does not support **multiple resources to be passed as arguments**.
I too had a similar requirement and what I have done is created a python framework and passed the resources as arguments to that python script. Then using python, iterated over the resource names and invoked the taint command from python. It is working till now without any issues.

I have created that as a python framework so I am just putting only the code snippet for your reference

```
import sys
import subprocess

resource_names = sys.argv[1:]
for resource in resource_names:
    command = "terraform taint " + resource
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

save this in **py_taint.py** in the same terraform files folder then call the script as below

```
python py_taint.py resource1 resource2 resource3
```